# How do I check if an object is of specific types in Python?

Tags: python, types

I'm explicitly type checking an object and am stumped.

The following returns `True`:

```
>>>type(data_id['CharacteristicLabel']) is bool
True
```

I need to check if that object `data_id['CharacteristicLabel']` is either `int` or `float` or `bool`, so I thought of doing this, which returns `False`:

```
>>>type(data_id['CharacteristicLabel']) is (int or float or bool)
False
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: `type(data_id['CharacteristicLabel']) in (int,float,bool)`

Comment: Nvm, a simple `isinstance` with using a set of types in the second argument can do this... So basically `isinstance(data_id['CharacteristicLabel'], (int ,float ,bool)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value, but also consider `isinstance`.

Comment: @simplycoding note that isinstance != type, for example, False is an instance of int, but not of type int.

Comment: @simplycoding: there is an important semantical difference

Comment: Ah, thanks. Should've looked closer at the `is` part.

Answer (score 0):

use isinstance

isinstance(somenumber, (int, float))